# Uploading image with text using firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to upload an image and the image name to firebase database in android studio,but whenever i run it my app crashes.

```
  public class image_upload extends AppCompatActivity {

// Folder path for Firebase Storage.
    String Storage_Path = "All_Image_Uploads/";

    // Root Database Name for Firebase Database.
    String Database_Path = "All_Image_Uploads_Database";

    // Creating button.
    Button ChooseButton, UploadButton;

    // Creating EditText.
    EditText ImageName ;

    // Creating ImageView.
    ImageView SelectImage;

    // Creating URI.
    Uri FilePathUri;

    // Creating StorageReference and DatabaseReference object.
    StorageReference storageReference;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    // Image request code for onActivityResult() .
    int Image_Request_Code = 7;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_upload);

        // Assign FirebaseStorage instance to storageReference.
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        // Assign FirebaseDatabase instance with root database name.
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);

        //Assign ID'S to button.
        ChooseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonChooseImage);
        UploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonUploadImage);

        // Assign ID's to EditText.
        ImageName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ImageNameEditText);

        // Assign ID'S to image view.
        SelectImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ShowImageView);

        // Assigning Id to ProgressDialog.
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(image_upload.this);

        // Adding click listener to Choose image button.
        ChooseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Creating intent.
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                // Setting intent type as image to select image from phone storage.
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Please Select Image"), Image_Request_Code);

            }
        });


        // Adding click listener to Upload image button.
        UploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Calling method to upload selected image on Firebase storage.
                UploadImageFileToFirebaseStorage();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == Image_Request_Code && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            FilePathUri = data.getData();

            try {

                // Getting selected image into Bitmap.
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri);

                // Setting up bitmap selected image into ImageView.
                SelectImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                // After selecting image change choose button above text.
                ChooseButton.setText("Image Selected");

            }
            catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // Creating Method to get the selected image file Extension from File Path URI.
    public String GetFileExtension(Uri uri) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();

        // Returning the file Extension.
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri)) ;

    }

    // Creating UploadImageFileToFirebaseStorage method to upload image on storage.
    public void UploadImageFileToFirebaseStorage() {

        // Checking whether FilePathUri Is empty or not.
        if (FilePathUri != null) {

            // Setting progressDialog Title.
            progressDialog.setTitle("Image is Uploading...");

            // Showing progressDialog.
            progressDialog.show();

            // Creating second StorageReference.
            StorageReference storageReference2nd = storageReference.child(Storage_Path + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + GetFileExtension(FilePathUri));

            // Adding addOnSuccessListener to second StorageReference.
            storageReference2nd.putFile(FilePathUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            // Getting image name from EditText and store into string variable.
                            String TempImageName = ImageName.getText().toString().trim();

                            // Hiding the progressDialog after done uploading.
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            // Showing toast message after done uploading.
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                            ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = new ImageUploadInfo(TempImageName, taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());

                            // Getting image upload ID.
                            String ImageUploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();

                            // Adding image upload id s child element into databaseReference.
                            databaseReference.child(ImageUploadId).setValue(imageUploadInfo);
                        }
                    })
                    // If something goes wrong .
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                            // Hiding the progressDialog.
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            // Showing exception erro message.
                            Toast.makeText(image_upload.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })

                    // On progress change upload time.
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            // Setting progressDialog Title.
                            progressDialog.setTitle("Image is Uploading...");

                        }
                    });
        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(image_upload.this, "Please Select Image or Add Image Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


}



This is the java class




public class ImageUploadInfo {

    public String imageName;

    public String imageURL;

    public ImageUploadInfo() {

    }

    public ImageUploadInfo(String name, String url) {

        this.imageName = name;
        this.imageURL= url;
    }

    public String getImageName() {
        return imageName;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

}
```

I am trying to upload an image and the image name to firebase database in android studio,but whenever i run it my app crashes.
I am trying to upload an image and the image name to firebase database in android studio,but whenever i run it my app crashes.

Log errors

```
11-21 13:47:02.265 32446-32446/com.example.youngfeezy.feezy_gram E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.youngfeezy.feezy_gram, PID: 32446
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.youngfeezy.feezy_gram.image_upload.onCreate(image_upload.java:64)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6729)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6284)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1094)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.youngfeezy.feezy_gram-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.youngfeezy.feezy_gram-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown Source) 
        at com.example.youngfeezy.feezy_gram.image_upload.onCreate(image_upload.java:64)
```

App build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.youngfeezy.feezy_gram"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please post your stacktrace - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this/23353174#23353174

Comment: upload ur Crash logs ?

Comment: i have uploaded it

Comment: It looks like some dependency problem, could you post your your app-level build.gradle file?

Comment: When i commented on the FirebaseStorage instance in the onCreate method the activity launched, So am thinking that where the problem is from

Comment: Try to update FirebaseStorage version to 16.0.4

Comment: you have a problem in your MainActivity class,  check your menifest file, or simply make new project and copy paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void upLoadImage() {
    if (filePath != null) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading Image..");
        progressDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("image/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ref.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // Image uploaded successfully
                // Dismiss dialog
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(SendSnapActivity.this, "Image Uploaded!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })

        // Download failure report
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(SendSnapActivity.this, "Failed!" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })

        // Image upload in progress
       .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int)progress + "%");
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please select and image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.